# Не пишет в манифест gradle kotlinDSL , сборка kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Имеем сбоку build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSet

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70-eap-184"
    application
}
group = "dev.glo"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
application {
    mainClassName = "dev.glo.MainKt"
}
repositories {
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap") }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("com.google.guava", "guava", "28.2-jre")

}

sourceSets["main"].withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) { kotlin.srcDir("src/main/dev/glo") }
configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

После сборки проекта получаем

> no main manifest attribute, in d:\IdeaProjects\testGradle\build\libs\testGradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Просмотр манифеста говорит, что действительно main не задан 
Ну и состав проекта
[image: состав проекта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                mapOf(
                    "Implementation-Title" to project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version" to project.version,
                    "Main-Class" to mainClassNameProject
                )
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Это решило проблему